# Mobile responsive tables

Tags: css, responsive-design, css-tables

I’ve built a web application and am in the process of making the pages mobile responsive. Specifically, I’m dealing with tables. I found a write up that explains how to make the table switch from horizontal to vertical for tablets and phones which have smaller screens. This works great, but the page has 3 tables and I’m not sure how to adapt the CSS for the 3 different tables. 

The write up: https://www.liquidlight.co.uk/blog/article/tables-in-responsive-design/ 

Code Demo: https://codepen.io/team/css-tricks/pen/wXgJww?editors=1100 

The portions I’m having trouble with is the labels of the cells. The CSS uses:

```
td:before {
            /* Now like a table header */
            position: absolute;
            /* Top/left values mimic padding */
            top: 0;
            left: 6px;
            width: 45%;
            padding-right: 10px;
            white-space: nowrap;
        }

        /*
        Label the data
    You could also use a data-* attribute and content for this. That way "bloats" the HTML, this way means you need to keep HTML and CSS in sync.       */
        td:nth-of-type(1):before { content: "No Longer with Parish"; }
        td:nth-of-type(2):before { content: "Position"; }
        td:nth-of-type(3):before { content: "Name, City"; }
        td:nth-of-type(4):before { content: ""; }
        td:nth-of-type(5):before { content: "Religious Affiliation"; }
        td:nth-of-type(6):before { content: "Virtus"; }
        td:nth-of-type(7):before { content: "Background Check"; }
        td:nth-of-type(8):before { content: "Standard Code of Conduct"; }
        td:nth-of-type(9):before { content: "Technology / Social Media"; }
        td:nth-of-type(10):before { content: "Youth (under 18) Code of Conduct"; }
    }
```

The CSS adds a cell before each cell in the row which contains a label for the item. This would be fine if all the tables showed the same data and could use the same labels. The problem is that they don’t. The 3 tables all have different numbers of columns as well. 
How do I tweak the CSS to differentiate between the 3 tables? Should I use an ID in each of the td cells such as id=”One”; id=“Two”; id=”Three” and then target the td id?

I've tried adding id="one" to the first cell and using the following CSS to add the label, but can't get the label to show:

```
td#one:before { content: "label"; }
td#one:nth-of-type(1):before { content: "label"; }  
#one:before { content: "label"; }
#one:nth-of-type(1):before { content: "label"; }
```

In the design window of visual studio, the cell is referenced as td#one so I thought that one of the first 2 lines of CSS would work. No label shows. Can someone explain how to reference the cell in order to get the label to show? Once I get that to work, table one will have cells one to nine, table two will have cells ten through nineteen and table three will have cells twenty through twenty-eight.

Maybe instead, I could add the label to the main td cell inside a div that displays none or inline using media queries.

Comment: Maybe add the id to the table and reference it in relation to its child `td`s, like this: `#table1 td:before`

Comment: That works. I added the ID to the table tag and then referenced the table as you suggested.

Answer (score 0):

Use `nth-child` instead of `nth-of-type`.

```css
th:nth-child(1):before{content:'First Name'}
th:nth-child(2):before{content:'Last Name'}
th:nth-child(3):before{content:'Job Title'}
th:nth-child(4):before{content:'Favorite Color'}
th:nth-child(5):before{content:'Wars or Trek?'}
th:nth-child(6):before{content:'Secret Alias'}
th:nth-child(7):before{content:'Date of Birth'}
th:nth-child(8):before{content:'Dream Vacation City'}
th:nth-child(9):before{content:'GPA'}
th:nth-child(10):before{content:'Arbitrary Data'}
```

```html
<table border="1">
<thead>
<tr>
  <th></th>
  <th></th>
  <th></th>
  <th></th>
  <th></th>
  <th></th>
  <th></th>
  <th></th>
  <th></th>
  <th></th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody role="rowgroup">
<tr role="row">
  <td role="cell">James</td>
  <td role="cell">Matman</td>
  <td role="cell">Chief Sandwich Eater</td>
  <td role="cell">Lettuce Green</td>
  <td role="cell">Trek</td>
  <td role="cell">Digby Green</td>
  <td role="cell">January 13, 1979</td>
  <td role="cell">Gotham City</td>
  <td role="cell">3.1</td>
  <td role="cell">RBX-12</td>
</tr>
<tr role="row">
  <td role="cell">The</td>
  <td role="cell">Tick</td>
  <td role="cell">Crimefighter Sorta</td>
  <td role="cell">Blue</td>
  <td role="cell">Wars</td>
  <td role="cell">John Smith</td>
  <td role="cell">July 19, 1968</td>
  <td role="cell">Athens</td>
  <td role="cell">N/A</td>
  <td role="cell">Edlund, Ben (July 1996).</td>
</tr>
<tr role="row">
  <td role="cell">Jokey</td>
  <td role="cell">Smurf</td>
  <td role="cell">Giving Exploding Presents</td>
  <td role="cell">Smurflow</td>
  <td role="cell">Smurf</td>
  <td role="cell">Smurflane Smurfmutt</td>
  <td role="cell">Smurfuary Smurfteenth, 1945</td>
  <td role="cell">New Smurf City</td>
  <td role="cell">4.Smurf</td>
  <td role="cell">One</td>
</tr>
<tr role="row">
  <td role="cell">Cindy</td>
  <td role="cell">Beyler</td>
  <td role="cell">Sales Representative</td>
  <td role="cell">Red</td>
  <td role="cell">Wars</td>
  <td role="cell">Lori Quivey</td>
  <td role="cell">July 5, 1956</td>
  <td role="cell">Paris</td>
  <td role="cell">3.4</td>
  <td role="cell">3451</td>
</tr>
<tr role="row">
  <td role="cell">Captain</td>
  <td role="cell">Cool</td>
  <td role="cell">Tree Crusher</td>
  <td role="cell">Blue</td>
  <td role="cell">Wars</td>
  <td role="cell">Steve 42nd</td>
  <td role="cell">December 13, 1982</td>
  <td role="cell">Las Vegas</td>
  <td role="cell">1.9</td>
  <td role="cell">Under the couch</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: can you please explain the difference between nth-child and nth-of-type? I'm hoping to make this thread more informative so that I understand why I should use one instead of the other vs just doing it because someone tells me that I should.

Comment: To understand the difference: https://css-tricks.com/the-difference-between-nth-child-and-nth-of-type/ In this case it's nth child (any) of parent (TR) vs nth child (TD) of parent (TR). I've decided to stick with nth-of-type not that it matters in this case.